# How to read.csv today's file in R with out changing the date

Tags: r, csv

Good Day, I normally read my data into a data.frame like this:

```
Raw <- read.csv(file.path("~/Download/20170206_tx_history.csv"), 
                header= TRUE, sep = ",",stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

and it works great. However, I want this script to run with out any change in any part, as I'm trying to make R read the current date and subtract a day (data comes with -1 day) with :

```
currentDate <- format(Sys.Date()-1, "%Y%m%d" )
```

and get it to `read.csv` with this:

```
file.name <- paste(sep="",currentDate,"_tx_history")
test <- read.csv(file.path("~/Downloads/",file.name,".csv"), 
                 header = TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

This code returns an error. Any idea on how this can be done?

Comment: Which errors does it give? You probably just need `file.path(paste0("~/Downloads/",file.name,".csv"))`

Comment: 'Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file  No such file or directory'

Let me try that

Answer (score 0):

Try this (removed last "/" from path and appended the extension in the prior step with `paste0`.) The file.path function automatically adds the directory separator, the `fsep`-parameter, to each internal paste operation.)

```
file.name<-paste0( currentDate, "_tx_history", ".csv")
test = read.csv(file.path("~/Downloads",file.name),
                   header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

From the path used, guessing this is OSX hosted. (All the parameters given to read.csv are the default values.)